# SwiftUI/Core Data: Crash when using Save() on managed object context called from .onDelete modifier

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui, swiftui-list

In my SwiftUI app, I have a .onDelete SwiftUI modifier (within a Navigation View, List, ForEach, Link, etc.) that I use to swipe-to-delete a core data entity object.  Everything is fine up to and through deleting the core data object.  The crash occurs when I call .Save() on the managed object context.  Been pulling my hair out trying to find out why.  Here is a snapshot of the code:

```
        List {
            ForEach(claims, id: \.self.id) {(tmpClaim: Claim) in
                NavigationLink(destination: EditClaimView(passedClaim: tmpClaim, uuidString: tmpClaim.id.uuidString)) {
                    HStack {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                            Text(tmpClaim.providerName)
                                .font(.headline)
                            Text("\(tmpClaim.serviceDate, formatter: DateFormatter.editing)")
                                .font(.footnote)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        Text("\(String(describing: tmpClaim.serviceAmount).currencyFormatting())")
                    }
                    .contextMenu {
                        Button(action:
                            {
                                // code to create a new claim is here
})
                            {
                                Text("Duplicate")
                                Image(systemName: "doc.on.doc")
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onDelete { indexSet in
                for index in indexSet {
                    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext.delete(self.claims[index])
                }
if (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext.hasChanges {
                    do {
                        try (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }
```

The crash occurs on the call to .save() and no error text or message is given. If I move the save() call out to another modifier, the .OnDisappear() SwiftUI modifier, there is no crash:

```
.onDelete { indexSet in
                for index in indexSet {
                    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext.delete(self.claims[index])
                }
            }

.onDisappear() {
                if (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext.hasChanges {
                    do {
                        try (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Also, have tried putting it in a function and abstracting into that and calling function from the .onDelete() modifier, etc.  So using both the .OnDelete() and the .onDisppear() seems to work and just delays the save a bit, but I would think it should work all in the .onDelete itself.

Any help and ideas on this is much appreciated.  Thank you...